# Processing with JBox2d Hellow World issue

Tags: java, eclipse, processing, jbox2d

Using eclipse, I'm trying to write a simple hello world program in processing that simply draws a rectangle on the screen then has gravity drop it as seen in [this Tutorial](http://jbox2d.nfshost.com/processing/tutorial/part1.html).

The problem is that when I try to import the p5 package, it's not resolving so I can't declare my Physics object.  I tried two things.

1. Download the zip, unzip it, then import the 3 jars (library, serialization, & testbed)

   a. import org.jbox2d.p5.*; doesn't resolve but the others do

   b. Physics physics; doesn't resolve
2. Download the older standalone testbed jar then import it

   a. Physics physics; doesn't resolve;

Here is basically where I'm starting

```
import org.jbox2d.util.nonconvex.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.*;
import org.jbox2d.testbed.*;
import org.jbox2d.collision.*;
import org.jbox2d.common.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.joints.*;
import org.jbox2d.p5.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.*;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MyFirstJBox2d extends PApplet  {

    Physics physics;

    public void setup() {
      size(640,480);
      frameRate(60);
      initScene();
    }

    public void draw() {
      background(0);

      if (keyPressed) {
        //Reset everything
        physics.destroy();
        initScene();
      }

    }

    public void initScene() {
      physics = new Physics(this, width, height);
      physics.setDensity(1.0f);
      physics.createRect(300,200,340,300);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is in the [ZIP file](http://jbox2d.nfshost.com/processing/boxwrap2d.zip) from the tutorial.

All classes in `org.jbox2d.p5` are contained in `boxwrap2d.jar`. Also add `Physics.java` (plus the other dependent java files) to your source path.

Comment: I just noticed that.  Looking at that class, it seems a bit overkill but I guess he uses that package in other places.